# Best way to nest parseInt in Var in Head

Tags: javascript, nan, parseint

```
var start=prompt("What is the starting temperature?", "-40");
start=parseInt(start);
if(start == NaN) {
    alert("Input was invalid. Enter a new value.");
}
var end=prompt("What is the ending temperature?", "40");
end=parseInt(end);
if(end == NaN) {
    alert("Input was invalid. Enter a new value.");
}
```

I'm attempting to get the parseInt to get the alert to show up if the entered value is NaN. I am in an intro class and the textbook doesn't give many examples of how to combine these two functions.

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is `false` so you can't use `==` to compare these.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNumber%2FisNaN) function:

```
if (Number.isNaN(start)) {
  // ...
}
```